# When you export large text to excel (Office 2007), no more than 8203 characters are exported to an excel cell

Tags: python, excel, win32com

When you export large text to excel, no more than 8203 characters are exported to an excel cell. I think problem to VBA or win32com.client, if i use `openpyxl lib` - export correct.

> Error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

I have the problem only in office 2007, export so use 2007 office only.

In office 2016 export is working fine.

```
import win32com.client
import os


path_excell = 'c:\wa\Excel2.xlsx'
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
if os.path.isfile(path_excell):
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path_excell)
else:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.add
sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
new_str = '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9'
new_str = new_str.split('|')
k = 8200
i = 1
try:
    while k<8400:
        s = 'v'*k
        new_str[7] = s
        sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(i, 1), sheet.Cells(i, 9)).Value = new_str
        k += 1
        i += 1
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Error: {str(err)}: max {k} char')
finally:
    if os.path.isfile(path_excell):
        wb.Save()
    else:
        wb.SaveAs(path_excell)
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
```

Comment: *DON'T* use Office Automation to create an Excel file. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files which means you don't need Excel installed, you can just create the files yourself. It's far easier obviously to use a library like `XlsxWriter` or `openpyxl`.

Answer (score -1):

IT IS WORKING FINE FOR ME!

```
import win32com.client
import os


path_excell = 'C:\\Users\jainil\Documents\\book1.xlsx'
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
if os.path.isfile(path_excell):
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path_excell)
else:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.add
sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
new_str = '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9'
new_str = new_str.split('|')
k = 0
i = 1

while k<8400:
    s = 'v'*k
    new_str[7] = s
    sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(i, 1), sheet.Cells(i, 9)).Value = new_str
    k += 1
    i += 1
if os.path.isfile(path_excell):
    wb.Save()
else:
    wb.SaveAs(path_excell)
wb.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your version Microsoft Office  - not 2007

Comment: it is for just showing output in .xlsx file. i use office 2016 just to show output, is it related to python?

Comment: yeah now i get your question , you mean office 2016 is working fine but office 2007 is not, so i reccommend you to simply UPGRADE!

Comment: some users may have a lower version of office so we take from 2007 the beginning